# Use 1 ScrollBar for 2 FlowLayoutPanels

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, tablelayoutpanel, flowlayoutpanel

I have a TableLayoutPanel with 2 columns and 1 row. In each row is a FlowLayoutPanel in which I want to create Labels. It will have to much labels for my form and I want a scrollbar in it. I already got a scrollBar for each FlowLayoutPanel, but I would like to have

```
namespace Flow_layout_Panel_test1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
            flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
            flowLayoutPanel1.WrapContents = false;

            flowLayoutPanel2.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
            flowLayoutPanel2.AutoScroll = true;
            flowLayoutPanel2.WrapContents = false;
            //makes a scrollbar for each flowlayoutpanel

            for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++) //Example Labels
            {
                Label lbl1 = new Label();
                Label lbl2 = new Label();

                lbl1.Name = "lbl_" + x;
                lbl1.Text = x.ToString();

                lbl2.Name = "lbl2_" + x;
                lbl2.Text = x.ToString();

                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl1);
                flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(lbl2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How it currently looks:
[image: like]

Comment: Set the FlowLayoutPanels to `GrowAndShrink` and make the TLP AutoScroll instead?

Comment: I tried that, but the TLP isn't showing a scrollbar, my guess is that it doesn't show one because its one row or smth like that

Comment: Then, probably, the TLP's Row style is set to `Percent` (default) instead of `AutoSize` -- Of course, the FLPs don't want `AutoScroll = true`, but `AutoSize = true` and `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink`

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed it from percent to Autosize and now it works.